# Is there a way to simply write data to a file using visual basic

Tags: vba, xaml, read-write

I'm designing an application using visual basic and xaml, and was wondering if there was a "easy" way to read/write data to a file. Basically my application is going to need to remember a few variables (preferably stored in an array) on start up.

Comment: What type of application are you writing?  Also, where is this file going to be stored?

Comment: The application will take a users goal for a specific amount of money he/she wants to raise. It'll then allow the user to edit the goal, and edit their balance by depositing and withdrawing. It'll also do some math to display the percent they're at based on their goal and their balance. I need to be able to save the current balance, and the current goal. As far as where the file is to be saved, I'm going to have it local within the same folder.

Comment: Is this a web app or an app that the client will download and run on their desktop?  Are you writing a silverlight application?

Comment: This is going to be an application that the user will run on their desktop, it is not a silverlight application.

Comment: Seems pretty easy. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t4kyezf%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

From microsoft:

```
Sub OpenExample()
   Dim sFirst, sLast, sAddress, sCity, sState, sZip As String
   '' CREATE DATA FILE
   '' Open file for input.
   Open "Datafile.txt" For Output As #1
   '' Write data to file.
   Write #1, "John", "Doe", "An Address", "A City", "A State", "A Zip"
   '' Close File.
   Close #1
   '' RETRIEVE DATA FROM FILE
   '' Open file for input.
   Open "Datafile.txt" For Input As #1
   '' Loop until the end of file is reached.
   Do While Not EOF(1)
      '' Read data into variables.
      Input #1, sFirst,sLast,sAddress,sCity,sState,sZip
      '' Print data to Debug window.
      Debug.Print sFirst,sLast,sAddress,sCity,sState,sZip
   Loop
   '' Close file.
   Close #1
End Sub
```

From http://support.microsoft.com/kb/209231

Found using google search term "microsoft vba open for output".